# How to make my apples look like apples?

Tags: node-editor, lighting, texture-painting, color-management

How do I make my apples look like apples? What textures should I download?

Which colour should I use?

What node sequence should I have? (Could you please show me a screenshot of the one you do?)

A bonus help for me would be a lighting suggestion, but I'm more concerned about the apples.

[Wetransfer File](https://we.tl/t-RxZSKa0ZsR)

[image: botched red apples]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at a reference image of an apple (a red one), there seem to be 2 parts - "Skin", and "Spots", and they both seem to be "vertically oriented", if that makes any sense - they look stretched top to bottom. So, the "Skin" can be generated by using a Noise Texture (Stretched on the Z axis using a mapping node) as the vector input for a Wave Texture - the Mix node is to "soften" the effect (otherwise it's too "brainy"). The skin base looks like this:

[image: Skin]

The second component, the Spots, can be accomplished by using the Distance output of a Voronoi Texture. I stretched this on the Z as well, to make the "dots" more realistic. Note that we are using *Generated* texture coordinates (as opposed to UV), the downside being that not all procedural textures are "the same" in all directions. The result here is that there is unrealistic stretching around the middle. In this case, we can "hide" it pretty well by not mixing in the spots very much, and viewed from a distance, it should be pretty imperceptible. The spots base looks like this:

[image: Spots]

Here are the skin and spots after coloring:

Skin
[image: SkinCol]

Spots
[image: SpotsCol]

Since the "skin" texture is detailed enough, you can also use it as the basis for a *Bump Map*. Notice I mixed the value heavily with white first, as we want the effect to be super subtle. Bump map effect on its own looks like this:
[image: Bump]

And here's the whole thing put together. I also used the "skin" texture as the basis for a Roughness Map, but it's probably not necessary unless viewed extremely up close. Just use a value of 0.2 on the Principled BSDF or something similar:

[image: Full]

This is just for the outside skin, mind you, you will have to make a separate texture for the "inside" of the apple, and apply that to the faces that are "sliced".

Comment: Hello, @ChristopherBennett! Thank you so much for the extremely detailed help! Gosh, I'm so grateful (I was making the project as a gift to a friend because he has an apple tree and you've just helped make the gift perfect!) Thanks a million! You're the best! Gosh, your help is so much appreciated. I feel crying ACC. Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have two options and both can yield great results depending on what your goal is.

I would try a procedural Shader Node approach since I don't like UV mapping and working with textures.

Apples come in many colors, so there is no "one fits all" solution.

Try the Gradient Texture node combined with a ColorRamp if you want to make a color gradient. Plug it into the Base Color of your Shader and decrease the roughness until it looks shiny enough.

Comment: Hello Solomon, thank you so much for the prompt reply. I appreciate it! From what I got from your comment (you were technical), I think I did the node editor stuff and even the color ramp stuff! Could you please help me check out my file? Cause I was following a tutorial

Comment: Hi Brownielopped,

After looking into your file, I saw that the task at hand is way more complex than simply creating a shader for the apple skin since there are apples sliced open which need UV mapping.

I would recommend to first get familiar with the Blender interface, controls and navigation, then looking into UV unwrapping and Shader nodes. For a beginner, this is quite a complex project you have there and cannot simply be answered here with a couple of lines I am afraid. Sorry I couldnt help you any further.

Comment: Hello Solomon, thanks for trying to help and for answering me first. I reaaallly appreciate it a lot! Gave me motivation to stick with the project. Hmm, I'll take your advice and get more familiar with blender's interface and do the UV unwrapping thing and shader nodes. They've been my bane for some time now, so I guess this is my sign to suck it up and get to work. Thanks, Solomon! Have a great day!